# What to do with answers from a religious point of view other than Buddhism?

Tags: discussion, answers, moderation

When an answer (or question) seems to be from another religious tradition https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/221 should they be flagged or left to be voted on by the community? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've flagged it as "other" and expressed that it was more like proselytizing Hinduism. I guess until Hinduism gets out of beta, our Hindu friends have nowhere to go :)

Answer (score 0):

If that answer had been a question, it would have been closed as off topic.

Hare Krishna and Buddhism, by my quick google check, are unrelated except that they both started in India.